# rich:fileUpload -- Nothing happening?

Tags: ajax, jsf, upload, seam, richfaces

I'm trying to use RichFaces `<rich:fileUpload>` component (with Seam as the overall framework) to upload a series of files.  However, when I click the "Add" button nothing happens.  Absolutely nothing.  I'm not prompted with an open dialog or anything.

I have a JSF page with an , and inside of that form I have:

```
<rich:fileUpload allowFlash="auto" id="contentImageUpload"
immediateUpload="true" maxFilesQuantity="5"
noDuplicate="true" required="true"
uploadData="#{contentSubmissionAction.contentImages}" />
```

The page renders fine, but when I click the "Add" button, nothing happens.  The `#{contentSubmissionAction.contentImages}` property is a `List` of `UploadItem`'s, so I thought that was setup properly.  Has anyone seen this before?  Is there something in the configuration that I could be missing that could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the issue that was causing this.  The web theme the site was using utilized jquery and included it in the `<head>`.  This must have conflicted with the version included with RichFaces, because once I removed it everything started working again.

Answer (score 1):

Is everything been put inside a `<h:form>`? Have you checked the server logs for any exceptions? You may consider to play around with the source code which you can find in [this demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/fileUpload.jsf) (click *View source*).

Comment: Yes, everything is inside a <h:form>.  I looked at the example when I started working on this, and everything aligns pretty closely.  However, I still get nothing when I click "Add".  There are no exceptions or log messages.  It seems as though there is no activity at all.

Answer (score 1):

In case you really need the included jquery file in the head of your web template but still would love to use your richfaces upload component, simply add this to the xhtml page:

> jQuery.noConflict();

Of course that should be within script tags

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very strange, but I had a broken rich:fileUpload due to the following css snippet included in my page:

```
input {
  width: 95%;
  passing-left: 3px;
}
```

Removing that or modifying that to

```
input[type="text"]
```

for example, fixed the issue. 
I assume that this has got something to do with the generated

```
<input type="file" ... />
```

from RichFaces.